# Error while using variable declaration Incorrect syntax near '+@TABLENAME1+'

Tags: sql-server

```
DECLARE @SQLSTRING VARCHAR(1500);
 DECLARE @TABLENAME1 VARCHAR(30)='NOV19_COMBINE'
---------------TABLE CREATION WITH FILE NAME--------------------------
SET @SQLSTRING = 'SELECT
    CONVERT(VARCHAR('+ cast((select max(len(EMAIL)) from '+@TABLENAME1+' ) as VARCHAR(50))+'),  EMAIL   ) AS    EMAIL,
    IDENTITY (INT,1,1) AS RECORDID
            INTO FOI_'+@TABLENAME1+'_CONV
FROM '+@TABLENAME1+' A' 
    PRINT @SQLSTRING
```

Error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
>   Incorrect syntax near '+@TABLENAME1+'.

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue here:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR('+ cast((select max(len(EMAIL)) from ' + @TABLENAME1 + ' ) as VARCHAR(50))+')
```

where you are trying to select from a table defined in `@TABLENAME1`. That also needs to be part of your dynamic SQL.

However you have another issue with your `convert(varchar(` code in that you cannot use a variable as as the length to `varchar()`. I suggest using `varchar(max)` because that only uses the storage required.

I have also made your dynamic SQL safe from injection with the use of `QUOTENAME` which I recommend you use in future.

Fixed version:

```
DECLARE @SQLSTRING VARCHAR(1500);
DECLARE @TABLENAME1 VARCHAR(30) = 'NOV19_COMBINE'
---------------TABLE CREATION WITH FILE NAME--------------------------
SET @SQLSTRING = 'SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(max), EMAIL) AS EMAIL, IDENTITY (INT,1,1) AS RECORDID INTO '
  + QUOTENAME('FOI_' + @TABLENAME1 + '_CONV') + ' FROM '
  + QUOTENAME(@TABLENAME1) + ' A' 
PRINT @SQLSTRING
```

There is no reason I can think of to do it this way, but as an academic exercise, if one really needed the exact length of the `EMAIL` column then one would use the following query:

```
declare @SQLSTRING nvarchar(max), @TABLENAME1 VARCHAR(30) = 'NOV19_COMBINE', @EMAILLENGTH int
SET @SQLSTRING = 'SELECT @Length = max(len(EMAIL)) from ' + QUOTENAME(@TABLENAME1)
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLSTRING, N'@Length int OUTPUT', @Length = @EMAILLENGTH OUTPUT
SET @SQLSTRING = 'SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(' + convert(varchar(4),@EMAILLENGTH) + '), EMAIL) AS EMAIL'
  + ', IDENTITY (INT,1,1) AS RECORDID'
  + ' INTO ' + QUOTENAME('FOI_' + @TABLENAME1 + '_CONV')
  + ' FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TABLENAME1) + ' A' 
PRINT @SQLSTRING
```

This requires 2 sections of dynamic SQL, the first to find the length of the `EMAIL` column, which is then used to built the dynamic SQL for the actual query.

Comment: declare @t varchar(max)=
 'SELECT
 CONVERT(VARCHAR('+ cast((select max(len(EMAIL)) from TESTJAN_Combined ) as VARCHAR(50))+'), EMAIL ) AS EMAIL ,
IDENTITY (INT,1,1) AS RECORDID
 INTO Updates..FOI_Nov2019_CONV
FROM Updates..TESTJAN_Combined  a'

print @t                                                                                   output i got:                         SELECT
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), EMAIL ) AS EMAIL ,
IDENTITY (INT,1,1) AS RECORDID
 INTO Updates..FOI_Nov2019_CONV
FROM Updates..TESTJAN_Combined  a

Comment: i need max length of column to create new table from previous

Comment: @PankajDhatrak no you don't - just use `varchar(max)` and it will cover all situations.

Comment: 1st comment i put direct table the i got max length (50) as per but when the table name is not fixed so i need dynamic table name to put

Comment: Use `varchar(max)` and it will cover all situations and is simpler.

Comment: @PankajDhatrak Note the addition of the inject attack protection.